# Interrogate the URL hash fragment on inbound Mule HTTP endpoint

Tags: http, url, mule

I've setup a Mule ESB flow, with an inbound HTTP endpoint; to which I'm posting:

```
GET http://myserver/myurl#blah=xxx
```

However, i can't find the blah=xxx referenced in any inbound properties. Does Mule support this notation? And how do i get reference to this fragment?

All Inbound properties i've seen don't have the hash fragment.

Answer (score 0):

What I know, using hash is to identify a portion in a document, however what you're trying to do is more similar to using query parameters

```
GET http://myserver/myurl?blah=xxx
```

Then reference it in mule using MEL expression:

```
#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.blah]
```

Cheers

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have control of the URL, it comes from an OAuth redirect - indeed from Mule's own Oauth response.